# How can i run the Behat Scripts in IE browser?

Tags: selenium, behat

I can able to run the scripts in Firefox and Safari .But i could not find a method to run the scripts in internet explorer .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I started using Behat, these steps should help:
When starting selenium server use:
"Drivers\IEDriverServer.exe" should be replaced with the path to the ie driver (which you will need to download).

```
java -jar C:\xampp\htdocs\selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=Drivers\IEDriverServer.exe
```

In the behat.yml file I have:

```
default:
  paths:
    features: features
    bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/bootstrap
  context:
    parameters:
      browser: ie
      javascript_session: webdriver
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      browser_name: ie
      goutte: ~
      selenium2: ~
```

If it still isn't running ensure the protected mode is on the same setting for all zones (doesn't matter if enabled or disabled but must be the same).
You can use regedit to do this by changing the values at:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Internet Settings\Zones
```

And then modify the 2500 value in each of the folders (apart from folder 0) to 0.
IE should now run!